# Inverse relation of $x<y$ defined on $\mathbb N$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

The relation is this: $R=\{(a,b):a<b\}$ on $\mathbb{N}$. How do I find an inverse of this relation?

I can see that it is $R^{-1}=\{(a,b):b<a\}$ but I do not know how to prove it. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Begin by writing down the definition of inverse relation. The plug the given $R$ into that definition. See what comes out.

Comment: You mean $b$ $R^{-1}$ $a$ if and only if $a$ $R$ $b$

Answer (score 0):

$R^{-1}=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}:(y,x)\in R\}$

=$\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}:(y,x)\in \{(a,b):a<b\}\}$

=$\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}:y<x\}$

and change the letters.